# IEEE.numeric_std.all library does not allow for unsigned declarations

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to the whole VHDL scene, as I'm moving over from system-verilog. While doing a simple practice exercise, I find that I am unable to declare or use unsigned data types. I have tried the numeric_std library as well as the std_logic_unsigned library, even though I know the latter is not actually an IEEE standard. The error I get is "Unknown identifier 'unsigned.'" Also, it doesn't seem to have an issue loading the library, as the line "Loading package NUMERIC_STD" appears during compilation.

In the code below I have been getting the unknown identifier error on the lines instantiating the D and Q ports.

```
library ieee;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  use ieee.numeric_std.all;  

entity g_register is  
generic(
  G_DATA_WIDTH : integer := 16
);  
port(  
  D     : in unsigned(G_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);  
  EN    : in std_logic;  
  CLK   : in std_logic;  
  ASYNC : in std_logic;  
  Q     : out unsigned(G_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0)  
);  
end g_register
```

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the code you have tried to use.

Answer (score 2):

To use type unsigned (or signed) you need to include the following:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
```

Note, the error "Unknown identifier 'unsigned'", most likely occurs because you have also included the package std_logic_arith.   Note that while std_logic_arith is in the IEEE library, it is an open source package that really does not belong there.

Note that including the package std_logic_unsigned does not help and does not hurt.   It allows you to do unsigned math with std_logic_vector.   For RTL code, I recommend against using operators from this package.  For testbenches, I recommend instead using the IEEE package numeric_std_unsigned.  The package std_logic_unsigned is also an open source package and again does not really belong in the IEEE library.

Comment: Check out VHDL Math Tricks of the Trade at:  http://synthworks.com/papers/index.htm

Comment: I apologize for not including the code snippet at first, but I have been using the includes you have listed above, with the .all tag at the end of them. I just don't get why the unsigned is not identified.

Comment: @DaltonStichtenoth  your "end g_register" requires a ";" after it.   Beyond that, if you copy just this code to another file, it should work.   What tool is giving you issues?